# PySpark dataframe.show() causes memory error after Target Encoding

Tags: python, pyspark, out-of-memory, data-preprocessing

I have a dataset of 24 million rows and around 14 features, read from a csv file via PySpark. I can use .show() just fine before preprocessing, however when I apply a custom made Target (Mean) Encoding function on one of the columns, it seems that I can not use .show() on that column, due to a OOM error. I will be including the source code as well as the error down below, thanks a lot for helping!

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import xgboost as xgb
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, explode, col, avg, expr, create_map
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoder, StringIndexer

def target_mean_encoding(df, col, target):
    """
    :param df: pyspark.sql.dataframe
        dataframe to apply target mean encoding
    :param col: str list
        list of columns to apply target encoding
    :param target: str
        target column
    :return:
        dataframe with target encoded columns
    """
    target_encoded_columns_list = []
    for c in col:
        indexSuffix = '_indexed'
        indexer = StringIndexer(
            inputCol=c, outputCol=c+indexSuffix, handleInvalid='keep')
        indexer.setHandleInvalid('keep')
        model = indexer.fit(df)
        df = model.transform(df)
        df = df.drop(c)
        df = df.withColumnRenamed(c+indexSuffix, c)

        means = df.groupby(F.col(c)).agg(F.mean(target).alias(f"{c}_mean_encoding"))
        dict_ = means.toPandas().to_dict()
        target_encoded_columns = [F.when(F.col(c) == v, encoder)
                                  for v, encoder in zip(dict_[c].values(),
                                                        dict_[f"{c}_mean_encoding"].values())]
        target_encoded_columns_list.append(F.coalesce(*target_encoded_columns).alias(f"{c}_mean_encoding"))
        df.select(*target_encoded_columns_list).show(1)
        df.show()

    return df.select( *target_encoded_columns_list)


spark = SparkSession.builder.master(
    'local[*]').config("spark.driver.memory", "10g").appName('sl-app').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv("data.csv", header=True, escape=",")

indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="Is Fraud?",
                        outputCol="Is Fraud?_LE").setHandleInvalid("keep")
indexed = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
indexed = indexed.drop('Is Fraud?')
df = indexed.withColumnRenamed('Is Fraud?_LE', 'Is Fraud?')

df_target_encoded = target_mean_encoding(
    df, col=['Merchant City'], target='Is Fraud?')
```

All this causes the error:

```
C:\Users\Hai Nguyen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.FB5AE2TYXYH2IJRDKGDGQ3XBKLKTF43H.gfortran-win_amd64.dll      
  warnings.warn("loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:"
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/04/19 15:10:53 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
23/04/19 15:11:58 WARN package: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields'.
Exception in thread "refresh progress" Exception in thread "RemoteBlock-temp-file-clean-thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.allocateInstance(DirectMethodHandle.java:520)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Holder.newInvokeSpecial(DirectMethodHandle$Holder)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.Invokers$Holder.linkToTargetMethod(Invokers$Holder)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$RemoteBlockDownloadFileManager.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManager$RemoteBlockDownloadFileManager$$keepCleaning(BlockManager.scala:2158)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$RemoteBlockDownloadFileManager$$anon$2.run(BlockManager.scala:2124)
23/04/19 15:12:08 ERROR Utils: uncaught error in thread Spark Context Cleaner, stopping SparkContext
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
23/04/19 15:12:08 ERROR Utils: throw uncaught fatal error in thread Spark Context Cleaner
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "Spark Context Cleaner" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Hai Nguyen\Desktop\FPT\data2\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 142, in <module>
    df_target_encoded = target_mean_encoding(
  File "c:\Users\Hai Nguyen\Desktop\FPT\data2\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 92, in target_mean_encoding
    df.select(*target_encoded_columns_list).show(1)
  File "C:\Users\Hai Nguyen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 899, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "C:\Users\Hai Nguyen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "C:\Users\Hai Nguyen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py", line 169, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Hai Nguyen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o40441.showString.
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Does this mean that my new dataset is corrupted, or is there a problem I am unaware of?

I have tried to find a solution for this but nothing really works, I also see that PySpark does not support a Target Encoding algorithm, so this was the best I could find. I have also tried configuring my "spark.driver.memory", but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when the size of the data exceeds the memory available in system.

a workaround for this is using limit()

```
df.limit(20).show()
```

Another work around is using sample() or repartition()

```
df.sample(withReplacement=False, fraction=0.1)
```